# Getting RuntimeError while creating CreateGISServerConnectionFile using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, runtimeerror

I'm inexperienced using Python and keep getting a RuntimeError when I try to follow the instructions to create an ags server connection file on this page - https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-mapping/creategisserverconnectionfile.htm.

Here's my code:

```
import arcpy
outdir = 'C:/Project'
out_folder_path = '\\gis\users\Locators'
out_name = 'automatedScript.ags'
server_url = 'https://MyServer.gislan.local:6443/arcgis/admin'
use_arcgis_desktop_staging_folder = False
staging_folder_path = outdir
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'

arcpy.mapping.CreateGISServerConnectionFile("ADMINISTER_GIS_SERVICES",
                                            out_folder_path,
                                            out_name,
                                            server_url,
                                            "ARCGIS_SERVER",
                                            use_arcgis_desktop_staging_folder,
                                            staging_folder_path,
                                            username,
                                            password,
                                            "SAVE_USERNAME")
```

RuntimeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 314, in CreateGISServerConnectionFile
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(arcgisscripting._createGISServerConnectionFile(*gp_fixargs([connection_type, out_folder_path, out_name, server_url, server_type, use_arcgis_desktop_staging_folder, staging_folder_path, username, password, save_username_password], True, False)))
RuntimeError
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For the last parameter- the save username password-  in your function you put “SAVE_USERNAME”.  Try setting this to the Boolean operator True or save_username_password=True.

Comment: I think that’s why you’re getting the RunTime Error on line 20.  The function is expecting a Boolean value for that last argument/parameter not a “string” like it is now.  See example code in the link you provided for more specific details.

Comment: It's probably not the issue here, but it's best practice to use raw strings for paths. Put an r in front of your strings. `r'\\gis\users\Locators'`

Comment: @emil-brundage, you get the gold star! I changed it using your suggestion in the following two places and it worked with no error. 
`outdir = r'C:/Project' ... 
out_folder_path = r'\\gisfile\GISstaff\Projects\Locators'` 
Thanks so much!

Comment: @BeckyColwell-Ongenae Great, I'll provide the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using raw strings for your path strings. This can cause issues due to backslashes. Put an `r` in front of your strings.

`r'\\gis\users\Locators'`